# Battery Polarity

Tags: batteries, reverse-polarity

I was bored at work, and remember when i was little, putting batteries in the wrong way would stop the object from functioning, then decided to try reversing the polarity of the batteries in my torch, and as i remembered, the torch didnt function. I'm wondering if anyone can help me understand why it is that this happens, because theoretically, if you have a light bulb, and a switch in series, the polarity shouldn't matter in order for it to function (correct me if im wrong).
By the way, im an electrical apprentice.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

If the torch was using an LED, it wouldn't function with the wrong polarity, but for a standard incandescent bulb, the polarity wouldn't matter unless there was a diode in the circuit for some reason.  For other "devices" where polarity matters, usually a diode is employed for "reverse polarity protection".

Also some devices have mechanical means of reverse polarity protection.  There can be a structure which only allows the "nipple" end to touch a contact when oriented correctly.  I suppose this saved the cost of a diode, but it did the trick.

[Here is a design note from Energizer showing the mechanical "ribs" for battery reversal protection](http://data.energizer.com/design_hints/catalog/designhints_revprotection.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you did not have a complete circuit. Assuming a AA battery, the battery is flat on the bottom and has a bump on the top. Your torch would have a spring or some other method to make good contact on the flat bottom and the bump would make good contact at the other end. If the battery is put in backwards though the flat end may not be able to make any contact while the spring end is just fine. This also assumes we are talking about an incandescent bulb and not an LED which would be polarity sensitive.

Comment: Alright :) these would've been my two guesses. Thanks for clearing that up!